# Scraping same class Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape Home team and Away team from this page https://www.flashscore.com/match/hY5c1Bhh/#match-summary/match-summary

```
    # Get HomeTeam
    _ht = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "home")]')
    ht = _ht.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "participantName")]')
    _homeName = ht.text
    
    # Get AwayTeam
    _at = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "away")]')
    at = _at.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "participantName")]')
    _awayName = at.text
```

Output

```
Longford
Longford
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to store both of them in a list like this :

```
teams = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='participantName'] a")
print("Home team : ", teams[0].text)
print("Away team : ", teams[1].text)
```

Comment: I tried the same for scores in this page https://www.flashscore.com/match/OxfWpyjH/#match-summary/match-summary
`scores = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='incidentsHeader']")
_1hf = scores[0].text
_2hf = scores[1].text` but got `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @luca use the same CSS_SELECTOR if you are looking to extract team names `div[class^='participantName'] a` same code should work.

Comment: @cruisepandey yes it works, I can extract team names. But I have to scrape scores in middle of the page as well. I tried to use CSS_SELECTOR for `"div[class^='incidentsHeader']")`

Comment: @luca : try this css selector `div[class^='matchInfo'] div[class^='wrapper']`

Comment: @cruisepandey doesn't work blank output the previous code Index out of range

Comment: @luca : try this `div[class^='home_']+div div[class^=match] div[class^='wrapper'] span`

Comment: @cruisepandey this works! but scrape only the second half score

Comment: @luca : I am using this code `driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/hY5c1Bhh/#match-summary/match-summary")

score = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='home_']+div div[class^=match] div[class^='wrapper']")))
print(score.text)` and O/P is `0
-
2

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes and how to get Output `0 - 0` as well?

Comment: @luca : for that score has to be `0 - 0 ` in UI right ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232628/discussion-between-luka-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.` when trying to locate element inside other element.
So your code should be

```
# Get HomeTeam
    _ht = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "home")]')
    ht = _ht.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "participantName")]')
    _homeName = ht.text
    
    # Get AwayTeam
    _at = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "away")]')
    at = _at.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "participantName")]')
    _awayName = at.text
```